# Getting sounds to work right

Tags: swift, audio, xcode6

I am trying to add sound effects to a game app I am making in Xcode 6. Here is the code that I am using to play the sounds:

```
var jumpSoundPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var jumpAudioPath:String = ""
var jumpSoundError: NSError? = nil

func setUpSoundPlayers(){
    jumpAudioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Jump", ofType: "mp3")!
    jumpSoundError = nil
    jumpSoundPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: jumpAudioPath), fileTypeHint: "mp3", error: &jumpSoundError)
}

func playJumpSound(volume:Float = 1){
    jumpSoundPlayer.volume = volume
    jumpSoundPlayer.play()
}
```

I can get sounds to play, but it seems as though it will not play a sound until the one currently playing is finished. How can I get it so that multiple sounds can play at once and overlap each other?

Also, every time a sound plays it drops the frame rate down a little bit. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use

```
jumpSoundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

before using

```
jumpSoundPlayer.play()
```

Also the only solution to drop the frame rate a little less, is to set up all the AVAudioPlayers before using them or at the beginning of the game.